# Get Row Number for Consecutive Status and Reset on Change

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

So I want to be able to track the number of consecutive signs ins over weeks for Users. I have tried row_number() Over (Partition By State Order by Week) but the row_numbers do not reset when the state changes. Here is an example table.

```
user_id |     week     | state  
--------+--------------+-------
1       | 2018-01-01   | Active  
1       | 2018-01-08   | Inactive  
1       | 2018-01-15   | Inactive  
1       | 2018-01-22   | Active  
1       | 2018-01-29   | Active  
2       | 2018-01-01   | Inactive  
2       | 2018-01-08   | Active  
2       | 2018-01-15   | Inactive  
2       | 2018-01-22   | Active  
2       | 2018-01-29   | Active
```

I want the output to be able to look like this:

```
user_id |     week     |  state   | streak
--------+--------------+----------+---------
1000    | 2018-01-01   | Active   |  1
1000    | 2018-01-08   | Inactive |  1
1000    | 2018-01-15   | Inactive |  2
1000    | 2018-01-22   | Active   |  1
1000    | 2018-01-29   | Active   |  2
2000    | 2018-01-01   | Inactive |  1
2000    | 2018-01-08   | Active   |  1
2000    | 2018-01-15   | Inactive |  1
2000    | 2018-01-22   | Active   |  1
2000    | 2018-01-29   | Active   |  2
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT
    week,
    user_id,
    state,
    row_number()
    OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, state
      order by user_id, week) AS streak
  FROM
    t.data_table
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
  order by week;
```

My output currently looks like this:

```
user_id |     week     |  state   | streak
--------+--------------+----------+---------
1000    | 2018-01-01   | Active   |  1
1000    | 2018-01-08   | Inactive |  1
1000    | 2018-01-15   | Inactive |  2
1000    | 2018-01-22   | Active   |  2
1000    | 2018-01-29   | Active   |  3
2000    | 2018-01-01   | Inactive |  1
2000    | 2018-01-08   | Active   |  1
2000    | 2018-01-15   | Inactive |  2
2000    | 2018-01-22   | Active   |  2
2000    | 2018-01-29   | Active   |  3
```

Any Suggestions here would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-island problem.  The strategy is to define groups of rows with similar status, and then use `row_number()` to enumerate them.

One method uses a difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by user_id, status, seqnum - seqnum_s order by week) as streak
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by week) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, status order by week) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t;
```

It is a bit tricky to explain how this works.  If you look at the results of the subquery, you'll see how the difference of the row numbers defines each of the groups where the status is the same.

Comment: Your second `row_number` in the inner query has a comma that's causing a syntax error...I would've edited it with your approval, but it's not 6 characters...

Comment: I had to add 'status' in the outer query before the order by. My final query was:

`row_number() over (partition by user_id, seqnum - seqnum_s, status order by..`